# JPA not saving foreign key to @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using Spring with Hibernate as a JPA provider and are trying to get a @OneToMany (a contact having many phonenumbers) to save the foreign key in the phone numbers table. From my form i get a Contact object that have a list of Phone(numbers) in it. The Contact get persisted properly (Hibernate fetches an PK from the specified sequence). The list of Phone(numbers) also gets persisted with a correct PK, but there's no FK to the Contacts table.

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contactId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Phone> phoneList;

}

public class Phone implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "contact_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Contact contactId;

}

@Repository("contactDao")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao {

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(Contact c) {
        em.persist(c);
        em.flush();
    }
}


@Controller
public class ContactController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView newContact(Contact c) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("contactForm");
        contactDao.save(c);
        mv.addObject("contact", c);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Hopefully I got all of the relevant bits above, otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to manage the Java relationships yourself. For this kind of thing you need something like:

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "contact")
  private List<Phone> phoneNumbers;

  public void addPhone(PhoneNumber phone) {
     if (phone != null) {
        if (phoneNumbers == null) {
            phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<Phone>();          
        }
        phoneNumbers.add(phone);
        phone.setContact(this);
     }
  }

  ...
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Contact contact;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Is the `addPhone` method correct? It looks to me like the null check is in the wrong place.

Comment: phone.setContact(this) - it colud be a memory leak? or not?

Comment: Why do I have to manage the java relationship myself? What if I have a unidirectional relationship?

Comment: @FagnerBrack If you do not have `@ManyToOne` on the Phone class, hibernate will create a table to manage the relationship which will gamed like `CONTACT_PHONE` and hibernate will insert the required records to that table.

Answer (score 6):

In reply to Cletus' answer. I would say that it's important to have the `@column` annotation on the id fields, as well as all the sequence stuff. An alternative to using the mappedBy parameter of the `@OneToMany` annotation is to use the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

As a kinda aside your implementation of addPhone needs looking at. It should probably be something like.

```
public void addPhone(PhoneNumber phone) {
    if (phone == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (phoneNumbers == null) {
            phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        }
        phoneNumbers.add(phone);
        phone.setContact(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the Contact-Phone relationship is unidirectional, you can also replace  `mappedBy` in `@OneToMany` annotation with `@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")`.

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
  private List<Phone> phoneNumbers;

  // normal getter/setter
  ...
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```

Similar in [JPA @OneToMany -> Parent - Child Reference (Foreign Key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533676/jpa-onetomany-parent-child-reference-foreign-key?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the **addPhone** method is necessary, you only have to set the contact in the phone object:

```
phone.setContact(contact);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your relationship unidirectional i.e. can navigate from Contact to Phone's only, you need to add

```
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = false)
```

Under your `@OneToMany` on your parent entity.

`nullable = false` **IS VITAL** if you want hibernate to populate the fk on the child table

Comment: This one really helped me. Nullable automatically made sure to insert key in child table. Ur a savior!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```java
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "contactId")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Phone> phones;
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Long contactId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JPA this helped me

```
contact.getPhoneList().forEach(pl -> pl.setContact(contact));
contactRepository.save(contact);
```