# Hibernate OneToMany wrong binding from parent

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, hibernate-onetomany

I have a simple REST spring boot app written on Kotlin.

It has next schema: `Map` hasOne `Channel` and `Channel` hasMany `Headers`

I have only one action of controller, and want to save all my models in a single request like this:

```
{
    "channel": {
        "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If header is not set, all models relate correctly and DB insert order is correct too: `Channel` created first and after creating a `Map` with this `Channel`

But when i add some `Header` list - **Hibernate makes additional `Channel`** (with ID=2) row in DB and bind all `Header` models to this channel (with ID=2)

**Map model:**

```
...
@ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
@JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
var channel: Channel = Channel(),
...
```

**Channel model:**

```
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), )
var headers: MutableSet<Header> = mutableSetOf(),
...
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
var maps: MutableSet<Map> = mutableSetOf(),
...
```

**Header model:**

```
...
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
@JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
var channel: Channel = Channel(),
...
```

Maybe some annotation should be fixed. Will be glad to hear any advise. Thanks for all!

**UPDATE**

Save model like that:

```
@PostMapping("/maps")
fun post(@RequestBody body: Map) = repo.save(body)
```

**UPDATE 2**

If make an object manually, and declare necessary properties type as `nullable` - `channel_id` will be `null`

**add this code to action**

```
val channel = Channel(
        ...
)

body.channel!!.headers.forEach {
    val header = Header(
            name = it.name,
            value = it.value
    )

    channel.headers.add(header)
}

val map = Map(
        channel = channel
)

return repo.save(map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**

it found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533676/jpa-onetomany-parent-child-reference-foreign-key)

just removed `mappedBy = "channel"` from collection property and add `@JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because in your `Header`, you are creating new `Channel` each time an instance of `Header` is created. Moreover, you set the `CascadeType` to `ALL` which means that this newly created `Channel` is persisted also.

You may set the type of `channel` in `Header` to `Channel?` and set the respective `channel` afterwards.

**Edit**
To answer question from comment: `channel_id` will be set automatically after you assign the respective `channel` and save this `Header`.

**Edit 2**
First of all, I'd suggest editing models:

**Map:**

```
var channel: Channel? = null
```

**And Header:**

```
var channel: Channel? = null
```

Relevant part of code:

```
val channel = ... // your Channel entity that is already persisted, for example map.channel (if map was saved before)
val header = Header(..., channel, ...) // create a new Header and set the channel
channel.headers.add(header) // it's bidirectional
repo.save(channel) // this should be enough as you have CascadeType.ALL set, so header should be persisted automatically
```

Comment: u mean like that: `var channel: Channel? = null` but how set `channel_id` ?

Comment: @qwert_ukg Can you please post how are you saving those entities? Afterwards I update my answer. Thanks

Comment: can't understand how to assign `channel`? U mean i should build `Map` object manually?

Comment: Could u plz make a short example, based on my data?

Comment: I was create my `Map` object manually, from request data (but can't see the difference if it was deserialized into same object by Jackson) and in this case my `channel_id` is `null` in a `Header` row. but row is single