# Persisting with JPA leaves nested object's db foreign key field null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have tables with structure:

```
orders
- id: bigint(20)
- amount: bigint(20)

order_details
- id: bigint(20)
- payment_type: varchar(255)
- order_fk: bigint(20)
```

Entities:

**`MyOrderEntity`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class MyOrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public Long amount;

    @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "order", cascade = ALL)
    public MyOrderDetailsEntity details;

}
```

**`MyOrderDetailsEntity`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class MyOrderDetailsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_fk")
    public MyOrderEntity order;

    public String paymentType;
}
```

**Repository**:

```
@Repository
public interface MyOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<MyOrderEntity, Long> {}
```

I'm persisting `MyOrderEntity` in such way:

```
MyOrderDetailsEntity details = new MyOrderDetailsEntity();
details.paymentType = "default";

MyOrderEntity order = new MyOrderEntity();
order.amount = 123L;
order.details = details;

myOrderRepository.save(order);
```

---

After `order` saving I have **`null`** value in `order_details.order_fk` field.

I want that `order_details.order_fk` will be filled by `order.id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need also to explicitly set the `MyOrderEntity` to `MyOrderDetailsEntity`. JPA implementation does not do it for you. So add line:

```
details.order = order;
```

before save.

You can also add following method to `MyOrderEntity`:

```
@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
    if(null!=details) details.order=this;
}
```

to avoid boilerplate code everywhere you set the `MyOrderDetailsEntity` to `MyOrderEntity`.

But the best way is to set `MyOrderDetailsEntity.details` field `private` and create a setter like:

```
setDetails(MyOrderDetailsEntity details) {
    this.details = details;
    details.order = this;
}
```

to keep it always set correctly, even before persisting. Best strategy depends on the case.

See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533676/6413377) for more details.