# Trouble with Hibernate entities relation

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

I have a problem with a relation on Hibernate:

I have two Entities --> *Solicitud* and *DetalleAccesorio*, and the relation is:

I have one *Solicitud* with Many *DetalleAccesorio*, and I need to save the *Solicitud* with the *DetalleAccesorio*, and both are diferents tables on the database.. this is the important code of *Solicitud*:

`@Id 
     @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
     @Column( name="num_solicitud" )
     private Long numSolicitud;`

```
 @OneToMany( fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="codDetalle", cascade={ CascadeType.ALL } )
 private List<DetalleAccesorio> listaAccesorios;     `
```

What I need to save the same primary key of Solicitud on DetalleAccesorio?

Comment: Are you asking what is needed to save the primary key for your Solicitud table?  Also, what error are you receiving?

Comment: set the primary key of DetalleAccesorio with the primary key of Solicitud and save it.

Comment: Ok and what is happening?  Is an exception being thrown or is it not persisting?

Comment: no.. I dont know how to make the relation on the DetalleAccesorio entity with the Solicitud entity.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to set the relation in the child entity (DetalleAccesorio) like:

```
@ManyToOne
Solicitud codDetalle
```

Take a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814474/jpa-not-saving-foreign-key-to-onetomany-relation) and also this [documentation](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `mappedBy="codDetalle"` from the relation. the mapped by create bidirectional relation . in bidorectional relation the side with mappedby (the onetomany) not control on the relation any more. this is the reason that hibernate dosnt recognize that there is a relation here.
If you want to have bidirectional than implement it as it need to be. means both side need to annotate and the important part - you have to maintain the reference in java both ways!
[look on this.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional)

as you can see there in bidirectional (and i dont think that you need , so remove the mapped by and it will be solved ) you need in code to maintain 2 directions:

> Changes made only to the inverse end of the association are not
>   persisted.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it has a very simple solution

*If you are willing to have access to `Solicitud` from `DetalleAccesorio`:*
In the `DetalleAccesorio` class you have to have this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=fetchType.EAGER)
Solicitud codDetalle
```

It was optional. 
(It's not optional) In the `Solicitud`  try this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "Solicitud_DetalleAccesorio_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DetalleAccessorio_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Solicitu_ID"))
List<ManagerDetails> managerDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code from the entity DetalleAccesorio

```
@Id
@Column( name="cod_detalle" )
private Long codDetalle;

@Column( name="cod_accesorio" )
private Integer codAccesorio;
```

And the id "codDetalle" has to be the same id from Solicitud to save it (numSolicitud)...